# How to correctly allocate memory for same type of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers, memory-management

i have this class, its alot like node when creating linked list.

```
class Element {
public:
    int id;
    int value;
    bool parent;
    bool is_ministry;
    int children_count;
    int children_in;
    Element **children; //CHILDREN ARRAY
    Element* next; //TO NOT LOSE ELEMENTS
    Element(int _id,int _value,int _children_count=0,bool _is_ministry=false){
        this->id=_id;
        this->value=_value;
        this->is_ministry=_is_ministry;
        this->children_in=0;
        if(_children_count>0)
            this->parent=true;
        else this->parent=false;
            this->children_count=_children_count;
        this->next=NULL;
        if(_children_count>0){
            this->children = new Element*[_children_count];
        }
        else this->children=NULL;
    }
    ~Element(){
        ///delete children;
    }
};
```

And i need this object to have an array of pointers to same type of objects, array size varies on the given input - children_count.
Can it be statically created? Values are read from file. I have chosen dynamic approach, but im not sure if its done correctly, because it works, but after i add 3 objects, the whole thing burns down. So im looking for plausible faults.
I am making something like a tree. Where one element has direct access to one level down same type of objects.
**EDIT: MORE CODE**

```
    void chain_together(Element *_parent, Element *_child){
///CHILDREN_IN is and int which shows currently how much elements are in the array.
            if(_parent->children_in>0){
                for(int i=0;i<_parent->children_in;i++) ///CHEKING IF THERE ALREADY IS A LINK BETWEEN THEM
                    if(_parent->children[i]->id != _child->id){
                        _parent->children[_parent->children_in] = _child;
                        _parent->children_in++;
                    }
            }else{
                        _parent->children[_parent->children_in] = _child;
                        _parent->children_in++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Two things to look into: Your development environment's debugger and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Is `children` supposed to be a matrix?  A pointer to pointer suggests you want something like a matrix (2D) of children.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I am not allowed to use vector.

Comment: `children` is set up as an array of pointers to children. No children are created to be pointed at.

Comment: You mean on stack by "statically" ? Not possible to create such thing with dynamic size of array on function stack as local variable.

Comment: OK. No vector. In that case you will have to comply with the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to ensure your children are properly copied and disposed of.

Comment: There are children created! You just can't see them :(

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough code here for us to see how you are using the element after creating it, so we have to assume the worst.  The downside of this assumption is that the solution set is astronomically huge. [Please provide an MCVE.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: off topic: you can merge your two `if(_children_count>0)`s.

Comment: This is the problem i have: /*
         * If this ASSERT fails, a bad pointer has been passed in. It may be
         * totally bogus, or it may have been allocated from another heap.
         * The pointer MUST come from the 'local' heap.
         */

Comment: That happens, when 5 or more element array is created. :(

Comment: More code you haven't shown us. Sorry, but I have to assume it is wrong.

Comment: Mabey now its enough?

Comment: Usually no, but that actually exposed a bug. Maybe not your bug, but a bug.

Comment: Debugger..................DCV

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a walk through the `chain_together` method.

```
if(_parent->children_in>0){
```

If the child list is not empty

```
    for(int i=0;i<_parent->children_in;i++)
```

Visit at all known children

```
        if(_parent->children[i]->id != _child->id){
```

If this child isn't the child we wish to add, add the child

```
                    _parent->children[_parent->children_in] = _child;
                    _parent->children_in++;
         }
}else{
```

No children. Add the first child

```
    _parent->children[_parent->children_in] = _child;
    _parent->children_in++;
}
```

Walking through the addition of a few children to see what happens...

```
On the first child 
    just add them.

On the second child, 
    they are not the first child
        add them

On the third child, 
    they are not the first child
        add them. 
    they are not the second child
        add them.
```

See the problem? If not...

```
On the fourth child, 
    they are not the first child 
        add them. 
    they are not the second child
        add them. 
    they are not the third child
        add them. 
    they are not the third child
        add them.
```

This bug would have been trivial to detect by stepping through the code with a debugger. A debugger comes with ever compiler tool kit that's worth using. It is possibly the most important tool you will ever learn to use as a programmer.

Solution:

Test that the added child doesn't match all of the pre-existing children before adding the new child.

Comment: FML, I was missing break :D I do remember i did add it, but i dont recall on deleting it. :( Thanks a bunch! That did solve my problems!!! Btw, i do need to delete the memory i allocated in the constructor or Element, right? (in the destructor)

Comment: @user3687719 Break is not good enough. If you test against the first then add and break, that doesn't mean the added child wasn't the same as the second. Yes to delete. And you also need a copy constructor and an assignment operator to make sure the array is copied correctly. The default behaviour will have the source and the copy pointing at the same array and when one copy is destroyed, the other will fail horribly at some point in the future.